# How can I resize a ImageView from my XML?

Tags: android, imageview

I want to resize (height and width) a ImageView from XML at my Java Activty how can I do that?

```
private ImageView imageView;
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Width and Height by **xml**:

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imgLauncher"
   android:layout_width="50dip"
   android:layout_height="50dip"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

You have to change **android:layout_width=""** and **android:layout_height=""** as per your requirement.

Set Width and Height **Java** Code:

```
private ImageView imgLauncher;
```

**Bind** view

```
imgLauncher = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgLauncher);
```

Set **Widht** and **Heigth** by **LayoutParams**

```
imgLauncher.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
imgLauncher.getLayoutParams().width = 20;
```

**Refresh** view after **set** LayoutParams

```
imgLauncher.requestLayout();
```

**Done**

Answer (score 0):

Simply add code in your activity

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
ImageView iv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ivMyImage);
int width = 30; 
int height = 30;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
iv.setLayoutParams(parms);
```